# How to debug "General error: 1030 Got error 0 "Internal error/check (Not system error)" from storage engine Aria

Tags: mariadb, view, errors

(In other similar questions, the error number has been 168, in my case it's zero.)

This occurs on attempting to load a massive view (which itself is a select query on another view). Many JOINS are involved. So I'm wondering if I can see somewhere what limit may have been reached, and whether I can raise it temporarily, or if the only choice is to rethink the DB structure.

There nothing relevant in /var/log/mysql/error.log - is there other logging I could enable?

---

Version info: Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.5.12-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)

Answer (score 1):

MariaDB-10.5.13 has this [commit](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/commit/f03fee06b0) that potentially improved the error message.

You could try [CHECK TABLE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/check-table/) on the underlying tables though I suspect if there was errors here they would have shown up in the mariadb error log.

To test if 10.5.13 is released has fixed this error (unlikely, can't see anything in the [release notes](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-10513-release-notes/) or change log), or provides a more detailed error, you can run that `mariadb:10.5.13` container on your same data directory and execute the same query.

If you want to check if the soon to be released 10.5.14 release fixes it, you can use the `quay.io/mariadb-foundation/mariadb-devel:10.5` image (ref [announcement](https://mariadb.org/new-service-quay-io-mariadb-foundation-mariadb-devel/)).

Otherwise I suggest searching and/or [creating a new bug report](https://jira.mariadb.org/) including your configuration and table/view structures potentially with `explain {query}`.

If you really want to help out the MariaDB developers, obtain a backtrace with the [quay.io/mariadb-foundation/mariadb-debug:10.5 debug image](https://mariadb.org/mariadb-debug-container/), set a breakpoint with `b mysql_errno_to_sqlstate` before `r`, and obtain the full stacktrace where it occurred.